# which version of gem runs depends on if I sudo or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, rubygems

this is weird guys:

```
david@triton:/usr/bin$ /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem  -v
1.8.10
david@triton:/usr/bin$ sudo /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem  -v
1.3.5
```

Now I need to be using version 1.8.10 but I also need sudo permissions.

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `sudo`? Because you probably do not (and should not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use sudo if you are using RVM
You do not need to access rubies like this by moving to the exact path. Write following at your shell rather.

```
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm gemset create <gemsetname>
<install any required gems you want to use without sudo>
rvm gemset use <gemsetname>
```

After that any gems you will use would be according to the desired version without doing sudo

Answer (score 0):

To use sudo with RVM you should use:

```
$ rvmsudo command
```